# Do I have to load javascript files at the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Not sure if this post belongs here, let me know if I should move it.

I know that we should always call `js` files at the bottom of the page.

However, I need to call a function in one of my views, where that function is defined in a seperate `js` file, which is in turn reliant on `jquery`.

So naturally, neither jquery or the function has been declared by the time I call it in the view.

#### _Layout.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using AuroraWeb.Resources
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("Title")</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_Navbar")
    
    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()

        @Html.Partial("_Footer")
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myscripts")    

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    @* google maps *@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap&language=@UICulture"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can see that my script bundles are all called after `RenderBody()`, which is where my view will appear:

#### MyView.cshtml

```
<script>
    selectableGrid('@Url.Action("Details", "Lead")/');
</script>
```

Where `selectableGrid` is defined in one of the scripts rendered in `_Layout`. Obviously this throws

> ReferenceError: selectableGrid is not defined

What is the right approach here? Do I just have to put all my javascript references at the top of the layout page?

Comment: whatever jquery plugin add it should be below the jquery library

Comment: The script in `MyView.cshtml` should be inside `@section scripts { .. }` so its rendered at the placeholder defined by `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

Comment: The _right_ approach would be to stop using “shit where they eat”-kind of functions - in this case meaning, functions that create output right in the place where they were called. That should be replaced with functionality that can bind to certain DOM elements (via selectors, element references passed in, ...) and will insert the desired content into those, but not bound to being called in a specific place.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks stephen I got it working. If you write up an answer I will accept

Comment: @CBroe I have no idea what you mean. Basically the script in `selectableGrid` just toggles styles on a row in `WebGrid` when hovering, and also adds a click function to navigate to the controller shown

Comment: There is nothing wrong in placing scripts in the head, you just have to be aware of it's side effects.  The advantage of placing scripts at the bottom of the body is you can get first render faster, as the body scripts can run deferred.  Jquery isn't something you really have to defer, there are a lot of libs that use jquery, CDN caching will be high etc.  Even here on Stack Overflow, they have loaded jQuery into the head.

Comment: @KeithThanks for your comment Keith. Yes I normally load it in the head just to overcome the problem mentioned here and I have never really had issues with it, but I know it can be an issue and wondered how exactly this is dealt with in asp mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render the scripts in your view at the placeholder defined by `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`, you need to add it inside a `@section scripts {` (note this can go anywhere, but typically at the bottom of the view)

In `MyView.cshtml`

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        selectableGrid('@Url.Action("Details", "Lead")/');
    </script>
}
```